# load table using jQuery and then edit some cells inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know how to edit some table cells inline and online with jquery (I managed to do this with DataTable-editable plug-in and x-editable plug-in).

I also know how to load table from my php file to frontend html file using jQuery load() ajax method.

But editing is not working when table is loaded with jQuery.

part of my file.html:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs-1").load("action.php?action=webList&user=1").ready(function() {;
        $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
        $('#editable').editable();
    });
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();            
});
```

x-editable plug-in don't even add editable class to  (without load(), it does)

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML as well :)

Comment: you have a stray `;` at the end of the second line.

Comment: And you're misusing `.ready()` when you call it on the `#tabs-1` jQuery object.

Comment: also try:    `$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
    $('#editable').editable();
    $("#tabs-1").load("action.php?action=webList&user=1");  
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();   
   });`

Comment: Get rid of `).ready(function() {;` on the second line and replace it with `, function() {` and it may work.

Comment: @squint yes, thanks! working now